# Helicoid is developable surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Please help me to prove that helicoid whose parametric equation is given by
$$x=u\cos v, y= u\sin v, z=pu$$
is developable, where $p$ is a constant and $u,v$ are the curvelinear coordinates of the surface. 
 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I cannot do that, as it is false.

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface#Non-developable_surface), the helicoid is ruled, but non-developable.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicoid) you can find a formula for the non-zero Gaussian curvature.